# Graceful fail with cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake that compiles various things: some C libraries, some C programs and some higher level SWIG bindings in C for JNI.

How do I do the equivalement of the following pseudocode in my CMakeLists.txt ?

```
Compile the C targets
if JDK and SWIG are present find_package(SWIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS java), and cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
  -> compile the Swig targets
else
  -> message("Missing JDK")
endif
```

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "graceful fail" and which line of your pseudocode uses this behavior. If you want to print "Missing JDK" and terminate configuration with the error, then use `message(FATAL_ERROR "Missing JDK")`. Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html#general-messages

Comment: Yeah, maybe I wasn't clear enough. If there's no java/jni/swig, I just want to ignore all the targets related to that.

Comment: "I just want to ignore all the targets" - Just do not create these targets. That is, create targets conditionally, under `if()` branch. Being called without `REQUIRED` keyword, `find_package(SWIG ...)` will set `SWIG_FOUND` variable to TRUE if SWIG has been found and to FALSE otherwise. So with `if(SWIG_FOUND)` you could check whether SWIG has been successfully found.